# Use LDAP server credentials and local user

Tags: linux

I want to configure Centos to use LDAP users and also local users. Is this possible or I have to use only one?

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, forgive me if its not correct, but this will definitely be a very close first guess :

in /etc/pam.d/common-auth enter the following lines

```
auth    sufficient                   pam_ldap.so
auth    sufficient                   pam_unix.so
```

Just a side note though: before you start playing with PAM's configuration, make sure you have a root terminal running safely somewhere. If authentication becomes screwed for some reason, you will need to revert your changes